# Detectng which page the current page in php has been forwarded from?

Tags: php

First of all i am very very new to php. I have a page in php named CurrentPage.php. CurrentPage.php is forwarded from a page named PreviousPage.php using the method

`header('Location:CurrentPage.php')`.

Now after being forwarded to the page named CurrentPage.php  is it possible to find out that this page has been forwarded from PreviousPage.php?(without using sessions).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `Referer` header<sup>1</sup> when it is available, but it is not guaranteed to be available
(or correct; it can be modified by a malicious user):

```
echo $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
```

<sup>1</sup> Yes, it really is misspelled.

Comment: Worth mentioning that this can be altered by the user and is not 100% trustworthy.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you want to keep referrals from your own website, in which case, check this out:

[Alternative for $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] PHP variable in MSIE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966059/alternative-for-serverhttp-referer-php-variable-in-msie)