# Client url during AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, cross-domain

I have a CORS supported AJAX server hosted made in PHP. Since it is CORS supported, users anywhere and on any domain can access it. I want to filter our users of certain domains. Is it possible to know which domain the AJAX requests are coming from, so I could filter them out directly in the PHP code?

Comment: you can use the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` variable to get the url where the user came from, you can log those requests in whichever way you like and create a blacklisting setup on the server

Comment: I know about this global, but does it work only for the normal browser requests (where you type the address in the bar) or also works for ajax requests too?

Comment: This is not working. The value in this global is empty string. Any other method?

Comment: some user agents don't fill this value in. I'll look for an alternate method

Comment: this looks like the best method I can find: [Alternative for `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` PHP variable in MSIE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966059/alternative-for-serverhttp-referer-php-variable-in-msie)

Comment: It's also not working for mozilla firefox :S

Comment: i would say to just change the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` part of the CORS to be specific to your website and any other approved domains. this will just require a bit more work on your part if users say they can't connect to the server from where ever they are

Comment: I think this approach will not work because in Ajax the page is not "referred" to the server. As in, the user does not click any link leading to the server page. Any help?

Comment: I want to keep my server accessible to **everyone** except _some_ domains. Making an allow list would virtually span infinite items :S