# $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] not working on IE

Tags: php, internet-explorer

I have the following code to determine the URL used to load a page, it works in all browsers except IE.

Is this a known issue?

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) 
    {
    //correct domain:
    $domain=parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    if( strpos($ar['host'], 'mydomain.com') === false )
        {
        } 
        else 
        {
        echo $domain['host'];
        }
    }
```

Is there a different way to get the URL that the user is using? Essentially I need to know what URL the user has entered to determine what to display on the screen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternative for $\_SERVER\['HTTP\_REFERER'\] PHP variable in MSIE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966059/alternative-for-serverhttp-referer-php-variable-in-msie)

Comment: **Related:** https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/178066/info-internet-explorer-does-not-send-referer-header-in-unsecured-situa

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the full URL in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Is this a known issue?*

Yes:

> **'HTTP_REFERER'**
>
> The address of the page (if any) which referred the
> user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all
> user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify
> HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

Also the above differs from what you want:

> *Is there a different way to get the URL that the user is using? Essentially I need to know what URL the user has entered to determine
> what to display on the screen.*

`REQUEST_URI` is what you are looking for:

> **'REQUEST_URI'**
>
> The URI which was given in order to access this page;

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Also see: [Get the full URL in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php)