# IE Popup targeting issue with Javascript referrer hack

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, popup, referrer

I've run across some code that is using the following type of referrer hack to pass along referrer information to a popup window via Javascript in IE:

```
    var targetName = "linkTarget";
    _win = window.open("", targetName, 'width=800,height=480,resizable=yes,status=yes,location=yes,toolbar=no');

    var _link;
    if (!document.getElementById("referrerHackLink")) {
        _link = document.createElement('a');
        _link.id = "referrerHackLink";
        document.body.appendChild(_link);
    }
    else {
        _link = document.getElementById("referrerHackLink");
    }

    _link.target = targetName;
    _link.href = url;
    _link.click();
```

[HTTP Referrer and IE7 and IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460490/http-referrer-and-ie7-and-ie8)

http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2008/11/bug-421-ie-fails-to-pass-http-referer.html

In an interesting twist, when I attempt to use that method with certain URIs (including localhost), IE9 and IE10 blur the popup window and navigate to the target URL in the main window.

You can find an example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/geoffreymoller/JKXzk/

Any ideas on why the localhost version might change the popup and target information like that?

Comment: It probably has something to do with IE's security zones.  It might even be a bug.  Beyond that I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

`_win = window.open("", targetName, 'width=800,height=480,resizable=yes,status=yes,location=yes,toolbar=no');`

i think the window name in IE is limited to names like `_self, _top, _blank, etc...`  as a result any name not like the expected list might be treated like `_self`